# How do I stop OS X from automatically inserting closing quotes?

Tags: macos, keyboard-layout

I have recently inherited a MacBook Pro from a colleague who has left the company. One of the annoying features that they had set up is that in every window/application that I can type the system will automatically try to enter closing quotes when ever I enter a single one.

I think the main problem is I don't know how it is supposed to work, as sometimes it adds it in, other times it does not. Either way, I hate it.

The way it appears is, as soon as you type the single character `'`, `"` or `~` (and probably multiple others) an underscore appears underneath it and I have to hit the space bar to accept the single version (did I mention it was annoying).

I've looked in the preferences and I can't see anything that could be causing this.

Comment: Your first paragraph is broken.

Comment: You can also experience this feature on Windows by selecting the *U.S. (International)* keyboard layout.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These are called [deadkeys](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_key) and used to enter [diacritics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diacritic) to type `ñ` or `é` when followed by the proper letter (`n` or `e` in these cases). If you type a character that cannot be combined, it adds the character without combining it, as e.g. `~t`.

Select a different keyboard layout in *System Preferences » Language & Text » Input Sources*, enable the *Input menu* and open the *Keyboard Viewer* to see which keys are set as deadkeys in your current keyboard layout (highlighted when you press the required modifier, e.g. `Option`):

[image]

Some keyboard layouts contain keys as both deadkey and regular character. The British keyboard layout for example has regular `~` next to left shift, and as deadkey on `Option-N` (shown in screenshot). The key next to left shift also has `` ` `` both as deadkey (when pressing `Option`, shown) and regular character without modifiers.

You can use [Ukelele](http://scripts.sil.org/ukelele) to edit keyboard layouts in OS X if there is no suitable one by default.

Comment: Thank you both for the question and answer. The deadkeys have been driving me nuts for a year now!!! Now I know what to call them :-). Changing to US keyboard fixed it! Phew!!!